# "You cannot delete this post" error when voting to undelete

Tags: bug, status-norepro, voting, deleted-questions

I just tried to vote to undelete a topic ([it](https://superuser.com/questions/381549/my-etc-hosts-file-keeps-automatically-reverting-on-mac-os-x) was on the way to being a duplicate when the OP deleted it), and after I was asked whether I wanted to vote to undelete...

[image]

... this error message was displayed:

[image]

---

I didn't know that I'm not able to vote against the OP, but that doesn't make the error message text any less wrong.

Comment: @slhck No need to guess, just click the link within the parentheses ;)

Comment: Ah, yeah, I was just trying to undelete this one too. Maybe a mod could undelete it and close it properly.

Comment: I didn't see the link because [it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ) was barely visible due to the dotted underlines ;)

Comment: @slhck Nice try. GEMA provides rick roll protection in Germany.

Comment: @slhck can you repro this? I can't

Comment: @Sathya I now get "A moderator deleted … and you can't undelete it".

Comment: hmm try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows/5#5)? @slhck

Comment: @Sathya "Answers to deleted questions cannot be undeleted" :)

Comment: @slhck well, status no-repro?

Comment: @Sathya The links you gave me are two different situations – deleted by mod, and answer deleted through question. Maybe Daniel or any other ≥10k user can test on [this one here](http://superuser.com/questions/386029/this-is-a-test-aslkd-aak).

Comment: @slhck that post worked.